# How can I export EXIF metadata from Apple Aperture?

Tags: metadata, apple-aperture

I'm trying to export the EXIF metadata from my photo archives so that I can do some analysis of which focal lengths I use the most. Aperture has a "File --> Export --> Metadata..." option, but that seems to only include IPTC metadata and not EXIF info.

Is there any way to export the EXIF metadata to a text file?

Comment: I don't know that you can. My prelim searches turn up 3rd party tools to accomplish this for you.

Comment: besides the answer below (kudos, Adam, for finding your own answer ;), another possible potion might be to just export some very small jpeg files, and then use other tools to go from there.  This all just gets me thinking more of various features for the tool I want, though... http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/open-source-highly-scriptable-photo-management-platform-for-power-users-like :)

Comment: Aperture>File>Export>Metadata... seems to export all the info I need!
(Aperture 3.2.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that [Automator](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/scripting.html) has an Aperture "Extract Metadata" action that has access to all of the EXIF fields.

I was able to solve my problem using a simple Automator workflow that performs the following steps:

1. (Aperture) Get selected items
2. (Aperture) Extract Metadata -- With the option for "Tabbed Text" output.
3. (Text) New Text Document

I have uploaded the Automator workflow as [Extract Focal Length.workflow](http://www2.adamfranco.com/dropbox/Extract%20Focal%20Length.workflow.zip) for reference. This workflow took about 30-minutes to run on 10,000 images, but at least I got the data I needed out.

One note, be sure to collapse the steps so that the results aren't displayed in Automator if you are running this on many items as this will slow it down dramatically.

Comment: Totally what you need as the built in Aperture Export doesn't dump what you might want.

Answer (score 0):

Just notice the same symptoms too , Open Preferences in Aperture > Export , in the dialog move thing around like size to export and deselected the include metadata or Exif , went back to where i was to start , closed the preferences and went to export .  It work but not in Mail , went back to do the same and finally work perfect in both exports 
just like before new upgrade .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Are you saying there is a bug and the preferences didn't work the first time?