# How to let users make a photo selection online (pick flag rate)?

Tags: lightroom, software, photo-editing, metadata

I take all my pictures in RAW, I only want to edit the keepers (obviously) and my users want to make a selection themselves, so **pick/discard,flag, rate**. Is there a way to have them do that **online**? 
Perhaps trough a webinterface? I just want to know which ones they picked and which ones they want to throw away. Rating would be a plus.
So fas I haven't found it. I heard from someone a while back that Lightroom CC has the option to do that with the 20GB cloud storage you get, but I couldn't find any information on the Adobe site about that, or on youtube etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about web development, choosing a web framework/tool/library/vendor, and or other non-photography specific topics that we do not cover here.

Comment: Well it's about photography postprocessing workflow. It's not about web development as I'm not asking anyone to develop anything or talking about developing anything. I'm asking what photography software already exists? @dpollitt

Comment: How is this type of question different from http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-open-source-photo-management-platforms-for-power-use?rq=1

Comment: The question was locked by mods with the following message: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here." So you're right, your question is not different in type. That's why it was flagged for off-topic.